# What is the record for the longest 5-set winning streak by a player across tournaments?

Tags: trivia, tennis, grand-slam

What is the record for the longest 5-set winning streak by a player across tournaments? Nishikori is on an 8-match five-set win streak. Where does he stand in the all-time list for most consecutive 5-set wins across tournaments?

Answer (score 2):

According to [tennisabstract data](https://github.com/JeffSackmann/tennis_atp), Björn Borg holds the **male** record in winning 5 set matches in a row. He won **13** over the course of [1976 to 1980](http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=BjornBorg&f=ACareerqqP5).

Patrick Rafter won **12** in a row between [1995 and 2000](http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=PatrickRafter&f=ACareerqqP5) if we ignore losses by RET. If we do not ignore these, he won 11 in a row.

Lleyton Hewitt won **10** in a row between [2003 and 2006](http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player-classic.cgi?p=LleytonHewitt&f=ACareerqqP5).

The following players won **9** at some point in their careers: Tomas Berdych, Nicolas Lapentti, Boris Becker, Dan Goldie.